# How to solve equation $ x=W(a+bx^{n})+1 $?

Tags: analysis, closed-form, lambert-w

How i can resolve the equation $x=W(a+b x^n)+1$, where $W$ is the Lambert $W$ function?

thanks

Comment: Consider the possibility to obtain a series through Lagrange inverting series of the equivalent equation:
 $$(a+bx^n)e^{-x+1}+1 = x$$
The solution should give a nested series in terms of Laguerre polynomials.

Comment: P.S.: Where do you encountered this equation?

Comment: but if we apply lagrange inverse theorem:

Comment: you mean this theorem:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem

Comment: P.S.: after some manipulation, to find x, i obtained this formula

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be easy to solve. Since $x = W(y)$ if and only if $y \ge - \dfrac 1e$ and $y = xe^{x}$, you will have to solve $$a+bx^n = (x-1)e^{x-1},\quad a + bx^n \ge - \dfrac 1e.$$
Are you looking for an exact solution?

Comment: yes a closed form with lambert function ...

Comment: @Umberto: Is not $x=W(y)$ iff $y=xe^x$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is. I will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

**??HINT??**

Lagrange inversion of:
$$\lambda(a+bx^n)e^{-x}+c=x$$
gives:
$$x=c+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda^k\frac{D_z^{k-1}\left[(a+bz^n)^ke^{-kz}\right]_{z=c}}{k!}$$
Using binomial expansion:
$$x=c+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\lambda^k\frac{a^{k-j}b^j \left.D_z^{k-1}z^{nj} e^{-kz}\right|_{z=c}}{j!(k-j)!}$$

The derivatives $D_z^{k-1}z^{nj} e^{-kz}$ can be represented as hypergeometric polynomials.

**Remark/ Edit in response to comment of Randa Jaouadi**
If we place $b=0$ the equation to solve becomes :
$$\lambda a e^{-x}+c=x$$
and the series solution reduces to (warning: $b=0$ so only terms with $j=0$ survive: when $b=0$ $b^j=\delta_{j0}$ ...):

$$x=c+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda^k \frac{ a^{k} D_c^{k-1} e^{-kc} }{k!}$$
$$x=c+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda^k \frac{ a^{k} {(-k)}^{k-1} e^{-kc} }{k!}$$
$$x=c+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} -\frac{ (-\lambda ak e^{-c})^{k}  }{k k!}$$
$$x=c+W\left( \lambda a e^{-c} \right)$$

We have employed the well-known series development of the principal real branch of Lambert $W$ :
$$W_0 (x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!}\ x^n = x - x^2 + \frac{3}{2}x^3 - \frac{8}{3}x^4 + \frac{125}{24}x^5 - \cdots
$$
See:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: Rodrigues formula for generalized Laguerre polynomials:
$L_n^{(\alpha)}(x)= {x^{-\alpha} e^x \over n!}{d^n \over dx^n}\left(e^{-x}x^{n+\alpha}\right)$
we  have:
$$D^{k-1} \left(z^{nj} e^{-kz}\right)=(k-1)!z^{nj-k+1}e^{-kz}L^{(nj-k+1)}_{k-1}(kz)$$

Comment: Ah ok, thank you very much :)

Comment: but if we chek the value for $ b=0 $, normally we get $ x=W(a)+1$ ? but i dont see this solution with the final form ?

Comment: plase see the edit in my answer

Comment: Ah ok thank you "grazie mille" Mr  giorgiomugnaini